# Why might an object be missing from heap histogram?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm looking at heap histogram of a Java process between 2 points in time. Although memory usage has increased drastically, but I don't see the biggest object I used to have in the second report.

```
Mon Oct 7 10:01:27 PHT 2013
...
Size Count Class description
-------------------------------------------------------
850635192 9666309 org.drools.reteoo.LeftTuple
63220392 1556524 char[]
35109792 1462908 java.lang.String

Mon Oct 7 16:01:29 PHT 2013
...
Size Count Class description
-------------------------------------------------------
76589736 2190862 char[]
52513032 2188043 java.lang.String
```

The org.drools.reteoo.LeftTuple had consistently been on top of the list before. Since the sum of top 20 in the list is only around 10% of memory consumption, I think that it is still there but for some reason it is not reported.

What might be the reason behind it, keeping in mind that the Java process is almost out of memory? Is it in a state to produce inconsistent reports?

Here is the old generation info if it helps.

```
Mon Oct 7 10:01:27 PHT 2013
...
PS Old Generation
capacity = 985661440 (940.0MB)
used = 846694760 (807.4710464477539MB)
free = 138966680 (132.5289535522461MB)
85.90117515401637% used

Mon Oct 7 16:01:29 PHT 2013
...
PS Old Generation
capacity = 2239758336 (2136.0MB)
used = 2239758328 (2135.9999923706055MB)
free = 8 (7.62939453125E-6MB)
99.99999964281861% used
```

Comment: The missing object might have already been garbage collected!

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I know that JVM was not in a stable state at that time, but should I expect correct output from histogram even if it is struggling for resources?